# Determine whether the following function determines if array is sorted in ascending order

Tags: c++

I am trying to trace this recursive call, but my assumption that it determines whether an array is sorted in ascending order is incorrect. Any suggestions on how I can do this?

```
bool g(int a[], int l, int r) {

     if(l==r)
        return true;
     if((r-l)==1)
        return (a[l] > a[r]);

     else {
        int m = (l+r)/2;
        return (a,l,m) && (a[m] > a[m+1]) && g(a,m+1,r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not destroy your question after you have received answers.

Comment: Does your function `g` return `true` when the data is in ascending order or when the data is not in ascending order? Are duplicates allowed? It appears that the name should be `bool array_is_not_sorted()` to reflect the functionality implemented in the `if ((r - l) == 1)` part. However, then the conditions in the third return statement should then be or'd together; the data is sorted if the left segment is unsorted or if the `m` and `m+1` pair are unsorted or if the right segment is unsorted. Alternatively, it returns true if the array is sorted, but then the `>` operators need to be `<`.

Answer (score 2):

The last return line should be:

```
return g(a,l,m) && (a[m] > a[m+1]) && g(a,m+1,r);
```

If you just write `(a,l,m)` C++ treats it as a comma operator, the result of which is just the last argument (`m` in your case, which is mostly "true" and prevents anything else being evaluated).

Answer (score 0):

Walking you through how to analyse this:

- `g()` works on an array of ints
- `l` and `r` are used to index into the array
- `l` == `r` is a termination condition... always returning `true`
- `r - l == 1` implies `r` is expected to be more than `l`, cementing an understanding of them as the **left (lower index) and right ends of a range** within the array: if `l` and `r` are side-by-side, then `a[l] > a[r]` checks for **descending** order
- `m = (l + r) / 2` - this is finding a midway point between the left and right ends, but crucially *if `l + r` is odd it rounds down*, so we'd better consider this "edge case" when understanding the algorithm
- the return statement...

  - as kvark says in his answer, it's certainly meant to be `g(a,l,m)`... which would mean do the same kind of processing on the range `l..m`
  - `&& a(m) > a[m+1] &&` tests for **descending** order
  - `g(a, m+1, r)` does the same kind of processing on the range `m+1..r`

So... when r-l > 1 there are 2 or more elements to be considered.  If we start at the smallest gap not special-cased (2) and work our way through larger gaps until we've established a clear trend of relying on proven-working smaller gaps:

- if r-l == 2: m = 1, resolves to `g(a,l,l+1)` (which tests a[l] > a[l+1]) `&& a[l+1] > a[l+2] && g(a,l+2,l+2)` (latter always true), so two important tests are `a[l] > a[l+1] > a[l+2]` (using maths semantics)
- if r-l == 3: m = 1, as above except the last recursive call becomes `g(a,l+2,l+3)`, which will test `a[l+2] > a[l+3]`, so it's working to ensure they're all in order
- if r-l == 4, m = 2, resolves to `g(a, l, l+2)` (which we proved to ourselves works above) `&& a[l+2] > a[l+3] && g(a,l+3,l+4)` (for the last, `r-l == 1` which we also observed above works)...

Clearly when r-l == 5 `g()` recurses to test r-l gaps of 2 and 3 (proven above), 6 tests 3 and 3, 7 4 and 3 etc... so we can see if works for any size r-l gap.